# Protecting SQL injection in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-injection

So.. someone is trying to get his/her way into my server..

from the logs I see that they are trying to do some php-based attacks, but still I want to mitigate this..

they are trying to inject SQL via this URL

```
/sign_in?t=login'+union+select+char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33)+--+
```

so in a Rails enviroment, this goes in the params hash as

```
{"t"=>"login' union select char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33),char(38,126,33) -- "}
```

since I whitelist the `t` parameter, its not a problem here, But I want to make sure other urls are fine if I forget to whitelist there

First, I'm not sure what they are trying to achieve with this attack.

Second, on a

```
Model.find params[:id]
```

would Rails clean the input in this case? or must I do it myself?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't build your own condition by using pure strings, like:

```
User.where("t LIKE '%#{params[:t]}%'")
```

Instead, it should be Array Conditions following this:

```
User.where("t = ?", params[:t])
```

I think that is pretty much safe in most Rails applications.

Furture reading at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

So, I think you don't need to escape string by yourself if you use proper Rails method (which it will take care the cleaning part for you)

Comment: is User.where("t = ?", "%#{params[:t]}%") safe?

Comment: yes, it is. It will give the same result as `User.where("t = ?", params[:t])`